# Shoot in different directions in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm having some troubles with the game I'm making. My character shoots bullets, but when it comes to shooting them in different directions it does not work properly. When it shoots the bullets follow the character's direction. Below I post the code.

```
var Bulli:Array = new Array();
var ShootTimer:Timer = new Timer(0);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startShootTimer);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopShootTimer);
ShootTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, shootBullo);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, mainLoop);

function startShootTimer(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    ShootTimer.start();
}
function stopShootTimer(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    ShootTimer.stop();
}       
function shootBullo(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    var bullo:Bullo = new Bullo();
    bullo.x = Jumbo.x;
    bullo.y = Jumbo.y - 50; 

    if(destra)
    {
        bullo.dir = destra;
    }
    else
    {
        bullo.dir = sinistra;
    }

    addChild(bullo);
    Bulli.push(bullo);
}       
function mainLoop (e:Event):void
{
    for (var b:int = 0; b < Bulli.length; b++)
    {
        if (Bulli[b].dir == destra)
        {
            Bulli[b].x += 10;
        }
        else
        {
            Bulli[b].x -= 10;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please tell me what type of variable is destra and where are you setting it?

Answer (score 1):

Don't add that listener to Stage, instead add it to each unique `bullo`...

```
//# not to Stage...
//stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, mainLoop);
```

Try this (untested but may be useful for some ideas):

```
function shootBullo(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    var bullo:Bullo = new Bullo();
    bullo.x = Jumbo.x;
    bullo.y = Jumbo.y - 50; 

    if(destra) { bullo.dir = destra; }
    else { bullo.dir = sinistra; }

    bullo.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, mainLoop);
}

function mainLoop (e:Event):void //the "e" of this function parameter is each unique "Bullo"
{
    //# currentTarget is whichever "bullo" is talking to this Event (via Listener).
    if (e.currentTarget.dir == destra) 
    { e.currentTarget.x += 10; }

    else { e.currentTarget.x -= 10; }

}
```